# Mixing chrome.i18n (internationalization method) into templates

Tags: javascript, template, backbone.js, i18n

I'm mixing [chrome.i18n](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/i18n.html) into my templates as `templateHelpers` with [Backbone.Marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.view.md#viewtemplatehelpers).

```
templateHelpers: function () {
    return {
        //  Mix in chrome to reference internationalize.
        'chrome.i18n': chrome.i18n,
        instant: this.instant
    };
}
```

and here's my template:

```
<% if( instant ) { %>
    <img class="item-thumb" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= video.get('id') %>/default.jpg" />
<% } else { %>
    <img class="item-thumb" data-original="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<%= video.get('id') %>/default.jpg" />
<% } %>

<span class="item-title" title="<%= video.get('title') %>"><%= video.get('title') %></span>

<span class="item-details">
    <% if( video.get('highDefinition') ) { %>
        <%= chrome.i18n.getMessage('hd') %> · 
    <% } %>
    <span class="item-duration">
        <%= video.get('prettyDuration') %>  
    </span>
</span>

<span class="hover-actions">
    <button class="button-icon playInStream" title="<%= chrome.i18n.getMessage('play') %>">
        <i class="fa fa-play"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="button-icon addToStream" title="<%= chrome.i18n.getMessage('enqueue') %>">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </button>

    <button class="button-icon save" title="<%= chrome.i18n.getMessage('save') %>">
        <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

The number of templates being rendered could well be in the thousands. Would it be greatly more efficient to pass the strings themselves into the template, i.e. call `getMessage` inside of `templateHelpers`, or does it not make much of a difference at all? My thought is that since I don't use the rest of chrome.i18n, I shouldn't be serializing it, but I'm not sure if that's the case.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt performance will take much of a hit by passing `chrome.i18n` into your templates, but I still don't think you should do it.

Templates should be solely for visualising data where possible, sometimes this requires a small amount of logic, but you should keep it out whenever possible. I would much rather see this:

```
var i18n = chrome.i18n;

...

templateHelpers: function () {
    return {
        hdMessage: i18n.getMessage('hd'),
        instant: this.instant
    };
}
```

-

```
<% if( video.get('highDefinition') ) { %>
    <%= hdMessage %> · 
<% } %>
```

In the long run this prevents your templates from being cluttered with internationalisation specific code, which will also be useful if you ever need to change the library.